# How to display a mysql View in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a MySQL View from a database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I would like to get the information in the MySQL View to my Asp.net controller.
I've tried making an SqlCommand where it asks everything from the View containers. How do I set information from the containers view to a different model(for example B0[Product] and Bb[Vessel]) and display it in one view?

```
public IActionResult TablesColumnDisplay()
        {

            List<SomeModel> Context = new List<SomeModel>(); // i dont know what model i should be using, or no model whatsoever?
            using (SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                using (SqlCommand SqlComm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM containers;")) //Containers is the final MySQL View
                {
                    using (SqlCommand SqlComm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM containers;")) //Containers is the final MySQL View
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        {
                            SqlComm.Connection = SqlConn;
                            SqlConn.Open();
                            sda.SelectCommand = SqlComm;

                            SqlDataReader sdr = SqlComm.ExecuteReader();
                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {
                                B0 b0 = new B0();
                                Bb bb = new Bb();

                                b0.Date = (string)sdr["Date"];
                                bb.VesselName= (string)sdr["Vessel_Name"];

                                SomeModel.Add(b0, bb); //doesn't take more than 1 arguments
                            }
                        }
                        return Context;
                    }
            }
        }
```

I will use ViewData to grab the information and so I can use that in my Index View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "model" should be a custom class that can hold both informations (Date and VesselName):

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public string VesselName {get;set;}
}
```

(Note that I used `DateTime` instead of `string` because I feel it's more appropriate to store a date)

Then you could create **one** model instead of `b0` and `bb`:

```
SomeModel myModel = new SomeModel();
```

And set both properties.

```
myModel.Date = (DateTime)sdr["Date"];
myModel.VesselName = (string)sdr["Vessel_Name"];
```

Then you can use `Context.Add(myModel);` (note `Context` and not `SomeModel`) and here you are.

---

In short, your `while` loop would look like this:

```
while (sdr.Read())
{
    SomeModel myModel = new SomeModel();

    myModel.Date = (DateTime)sdr["Date"];
    myModel.VesselName= (string)sdr["Vessel_Name"];

    Context.Add(myModel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I created a new Model which contains the items the SQL View contains and I can display them using a foreach statement using ViewData["Columns"] as IEnumerable<Project.Models.Folder.Modelname.